# How do you unitTest a Publisher -Subscriber pattern?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Hi
Wondering if there is a pattern to unit test a publisher subscriber pattern?

Any examples or suggestions?

thanks

Comment: publish subscriber pattern is out of scope for unit tests - that's integration or system testing as you test if components implement an interface correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test:

Arrange:

- Create a publisher
- Create a subscriber
- Subscribe the subscriber to the publisher

Act:

- Publish

Assert:

- Verify that subscriber received the published event

Perform a similiar test for multiple subscribers.

Not sure what else you are looking for.

Comment: fair enough.I was wondering if there was a specific pattern todo it

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write "real" unit tests, you should probably look into writing one test of the publisher and another of the subscriber. When these tests pass, you should do a quick integration test to see if subscribers can subscribe and receive a message from the publisher (as Mitch suggested).